# The Input Shape for ConvLSTM model for image prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to make an image prediction by using ConvLSTM model. But I am having trouble with understanding the data set that I should feed into my neural network.

I have searched on the internet and found examples like "Precipitation Prediction Using ConvLSTM" and some other models where ConvLSTM model has been used to make prediction. For the first trial I have chosen the model provided in the precipitation problem in order to see how the model will react to my data set.

def fn_get_model_convLSTM_tframe_5():

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(7, 7),
                     input_shape=(None, 101, 101, 1), padding='same',  return_sequences=True, 
                     activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', unit_forget_bias=True, 
                     dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3, go_backwards=True ))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(7, 7), padding='same', return_sequences=True, 
                     activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', 
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', unit_forget_bias=True, 
                     dropout=0.4, recurrent_dropout=0.3, go_backwards=True ))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(7, 7), padding='same', return_sequences=True, 
                     activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', 
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', unit_forget_bias=True, 
                     dropout=0.4, recurrent_dropout=0.3, go_backwards=True ))
model.add(BatchNormalization())


model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(7, 7), padding='same', return_sequences=False, 
                     activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', 
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', unit_forget_bias=True, 
                     dropout=0.4, recurrent_dropout=0.3, go_backwards=True ))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1, 1),
               activation='sigmoid',
               padding='same', data_format='channels_last')) 

print(model.summary())
return model
```

The entire code can be found here:
https://github.com/TeaPearce/precipitation-prediction-convLSTM-keras/blob/master/precip_v09.py

```
  As I understood the image fed into the model had the shape of 101x101 with 4 color channels. The same is the case for my dataset (I am not giving all the details regarding my dataset as I am quite sure ConvLSTM model is suitable for my dataset and for running out of redundant discussion). 

  I have the images of size 35x45 with four color channels. In total, I have 35 sequences and each sequence contains 140 sequential images. Additionally I have 1 more sequence on which I should do prediction as it contains 120 images (I need to fulfill it till the 140) I have tried to reshape my dataset and fit it into array of size (35, 140, 35, 45, 4). So know I have array so called trainx for training dataset. But the thing is that I am confused about the labels that I should provide (Even I am not sure whether I should provide or not as we are talking about sequential images).

 Can anyone please help me on preparing this dataset for neural network and explain the datashape that I should provide clearly
```

Comment: Sorry for typing mistakes that I made. I would highly appreciate if someone corrects them.

Answer (score 1):

input_shape=(None, 101, 101, 1)

the input shape is 101x101 with **1** channels

If you have images with 4 channel, take input shape as (None, 101, 101, 4)